# Chromium browser not installing

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, chrome

To install the Chromium browser, I type:

```
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

But then I get several errors. What happens after is below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.22) but 2:3.21-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
                    Depends: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (= 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 76.0.3809.100-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed or
                             chromium-codecs-ffmpeg (= 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: chromium-browser-l10n but it is not going to be installed
 google-chrome-stable:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16)
                              Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libatspi2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.9.90) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libcups2:amd64 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libdrm2:amd64 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libgbm1:amd64 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.22) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libx11-6:amd64 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libx11-xcb1:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                              Recommends: libu2f-udev:amd64 but it is not installable
                              Recommends: libvulkan1:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please Help.

Comment: Your problem is a difference in ubuntu suites.  Can you add `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer from Chromium specifically, but a general answer for this type of problem.

This problem appears when sources or suites start to get mixed with apt.  Let's say you try to install [`chromium-browser`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/chromium-browser).  The Ubuntu `bionic` suite ships version `86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

When you tried to install `chromium-browser`, you got a line that looked like this:

```
Depends: 
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra (= 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) 
                              but 76.0.3809.100-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
or
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg (= 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) 
                              but it is not going to be installed
```

Bingo!

This means that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` contain sources that provide a different version of chromium.

When looking in [official ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra) I found these versions:

- bionic: 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- xenial-updates: 86.0.4240.75-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- xenial: 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233

Since your version is between xenial and xenial-updates, it looks like you've found the package in an unofficial repository.  This could be a problem caused by adding PPAs or sources from other distributions.

Here's my guess about what happened:

1. You have an updated apt release file with all of the latest packages from official ubuntu archives, but you also have a PPA in there which isn't maintained and is out of sync with official archives.
2. When you used `apt install chromium-browser`, `apt` found the preferred version in the `bionic` suite.
3. Apt tried to install the `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra or chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` package.  The highest priority hit it found was from this unmaintained PPA.  Normally the highest-version found is selected, but in this case this PPA took priority.  That might be because of pinning, or perhaps you have the `xenial` source selected for that PPA and `xenial` has priority over `bionic` on your machine.
4. When `apt` found this version in your priority source, it failed because that version fails to meet the dependency requirements.

See [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) for why adding incompatible sources is a bad idea.

The solution is to clean up your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

1. If you are using `bionic` remove all lines that are related to other releases (except `bionic-security` and `bionic-updates`).
2. If you are using PPAs, be sure that you actually need something from that PPA.   Delete the PPA otherwise.  If the PPA simply has newer versions of software: [don't suffer from shiny new stuff syndrome](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome). PPAs aren't trusted sources and can contain anything.  Also they can become unmaintained at any time.  Take the latest version in your official release.

Answer (score 0):

run command to add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xalt7x/chromium-deb-vaapi
```

Run command to “pin” the PPA to avoid installation of snap package in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-xalt7x-chromium-deb-vaapi
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-xalt7x-chromium-deb-vaapi
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

After that you can install the browser via:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install chromium-browser chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

P.S - To remove from source list

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xalt7x/chromium-deb-vaapi
```

Comment: Why recommend a PPA?  Isn't chromium available from official repositories?